# change .txt files with certain conditions

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I have txt file with numbers with id discord servers (example:38748194014..)
the file should look like this:

```
213123123123
312312342423
64574476747457
52534653463636
```

so what i need to do with this file:

> 1. When a person writes a command, my bot must record the server's id discord, if it is already there, display a message that it is there (Add server id to txt file)
> 2. When a person writes a command, my bot should find the ID of this server in this list and delete it from there, if it is not there, display an error message (Delete server id from txt file)
>    `I know how to get discord server id i need only how to add server id to txt file and delete from txt file`
>    full explanation:
>    1.

```
 if my_server_id not found in servers_id_list:
  add my_server_id to new stroke in txt file
 else:
  print('File contain my_server_id')
```

2. 

```
 if my_server_id found in servers_id_list:
  delete my_server_id from server_id_list
 else:
  print('File not contain my_server_id')
```

tried to explain as clearly as possible, help... hee `cough`.. help me.

Comment: Unfortunately questions like this aren't usually answerable on StackOverflow because it doesn't look like you've actually tried to write code to do what you want. (What you've written looks like pseudocode.) See [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108551/what-site-to-use-if-you-have-a-gimme-teh-codez-question) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a text file is not ideal for this (I'd use a database), but to add something to the end:

```
with open(file, 'a') as f:
    f.write(id)
```

For deleting, you would probably have to read the entire file into an array, and then modify it and re-write it back.

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is working code:

```
f=open("data.txt","r") #use any file name you want
lines=[]
for line in f:
    lines.append(line.strip())
f.close()
def check_add(sid):
    if str(sid) in lines:
        print('File contain my_server_id')
    else:
        lines.append(check_id)

def check_delete(sid):
    if str(sid) in lines:
        lines.remove(check_id)
    else:
        print('File not contain my_server_id')
    
check_id=input() #server id
check_add(check_id) # or check_delete(check_id), depends which function you need


f_app=open("data.txt","w") #use any file name you want, this is for writing result to file after changes
for l in lines:
    f_app.write(l+"\n")
f_app.close()
```

You have 2 functions as you described. First one checks and if there is no id it adds it. Second one check if id is there and if it is then it removes it.